# transform javascript object by lifting nested property up to one level

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I failed to move a nested value up to one level. I want to move the name property up to one level, how can I tranform this

```
[{
    date: "1/11",
    collections: [{
        device: {name: "camera 1"},
        count: 10
    },{
        device: {name: "camera 2"},
        count: 20
    },{
        device: {name: "camera 3"},
        count: 30
    }]
}]
```

to this?

```
[{
    date: "1/11",
    data: [{
        camera: "camera 1",
        count: 10
    },{
        camera: "camera 2",
        count: 20
    },{
        camera: "camera 3",
        count: 30
    }]
}]
```

I'm stuck at http://jsfiddle.net/usjyc83u/

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of your code in your question. Also, do you need to keep the original as it is (and thus make a modified copy), or can you make the changes in place? Note also that in your example in addition to moving/renaming the name property, you also rename collections, is that on purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to map the array, and then map the inner collections array.

Note: this solution uses [proposal-object-rest-spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) that requires Babel's [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) to work.

```js
const data = [{"date":"1/11","collections":[{"device":{"name":"camera 1"},"count":10},{"device":{"name":"camera 2"},"count":20},{"device":{"name":"camera 3"},"count":30}]}];

const result = data.map(({ collections, ...o }) => ({
  ...o,
  data: collections.map(({ device, ...r }) => ({
    ...r,
    camera: device.name
  }))
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your main object is an array or a simple object. I have treated your object as an array. What I did is

1. map through the global collection (= "*do this action for each element in the array*")
2. for each object, create a new key: `data`. Its value is an array
3. populate the data array with the objects from your `collections` as an object in your desired structure ( `{camera: ..., count:...}` )
4. remove the `collections` from the object. (if you want to keep it, remove that line then)

```js
const yourData = [{
  date: "1/11",
  collections: [{
    device: {
      name: "camera 1"
    },
    count: 10
  }, {
    device: {
      name: "camera 2"
    },
    count: 20
  }, {
    device: {
      name: "camera 3"
    },
    count: 30
  }]
}];

// using ES5+ syntax
// 1. map through your objects
yourData.map(el => {
  // 2. set data array
  el.data = [];
  // 3. populate with required objects in correct structure
  el.collections.forEach(o => {
    el.data.push({
      camera: o.device.name,
      count: o.count
    });
  });
  // 4. remove the old data
  delete el.collections;
});

console.log(yourData);
```

```html
[{ date: "1/11", data: [{ camera: "camera 1", count: 10 },{ camera: "camera 2", count: 20 },{ camera: "camera 3", count: 30 }] }]
```